# Redirect all Lighttpd traffic apart from one folder and index file

Tags: web, configuration, lighttpd

I want the following rule to be applied

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.example\.com$" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://newlocation.example.com/$1" )
}
```

However if the user requests:

- index.html
- the root location i.e (www.example.com)
- tools/*

The request should be served normally

www.example.com/ -> Served normally

www.example.com/tools/style.css -> Served normally

www.example.com/example.html -> http://newlocation.example.com/example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match all the files you want to serve normally, and then use `else` to redirect the rest. Something like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.example\.com$" {
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/(index\.html|tools/|)$" {
        server.document-root = "/path/to/files"
    } else {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://newlocation.example.com/$1" )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me, but I am lookin for something similar like this! lighttpd is giving me a parsing error when using this setup.

Comment: I can't say I remember much of this setup - did you figure out the syntax error or some other way yet?